# How to set FontAttributes within XAML to both Bold and Italic?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, how do I set `FontAttributes` within `XAML` to both **Bold** and **Italic**?

**Example:**

```xml
  <Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic" />
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```xml
<Style TargetType="Label">
  <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold, Italic" />
</Style>
```

`FontAttributes` is a Flag, so you can pass multiple values.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for the code-behind solution:

```
element.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just keep use commas to separate them in the value field.

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold, Italic"/>
  </Style>
```

Make sure to review http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/

Comment: Thanks Stephane. Any ideas on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406185/how-to-make-a-behaviors-collection-a-resource-in-xaml

Answer (score 0):

```
FontAttributes="Bold, Italic"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts