# How to make a behaviors collection a resource in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

**How do I make a behaviors collection a resource in XAML using Xamarin.Forms?**

I tried the following:

```
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Behaviors;assembly=Xamarin.Behaviors"
xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:ViewOptions.Behaviors;assembly=ViewOptions"
```

.
.

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <b:BehaviorCollection x:Key="BehaviorCollection">
        <Behaviors:TextBoxFocusBehavior />
      </b:BehaviorCollection>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Here's a behavior:

```cs
namespace ViewOptions.Behaviors
{
    public class TextBoxFocusBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {   
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The implementation gives me a runtime exception.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the exception too please?

Comment: The exception: "An unhandled exception occured."

Comment: `Xamarin.Behaviors` is not part of `Xamarin.Forms` and not released by Xamarin at all. `Xamarin.Forms` already provide `Trigger`s and `Behavior`s, you might want to look at that.